# creating schema to convert pandas df to pyspark df

Tags: pandas, pyspark

I try to create a schema for pandas df to pyspark df conversion. Could you please explain to me what I am doing wrong?

```
# creating mySchema
dtype_l, name_l, true_l = [],[],[]
for col in df.columns:
    name_l.append(col)
    true_l.append(True)
    if df.y.dtype == 'int64':
        dtype_l.append("IntegerType()")
    if df.y.dtype == 'float64':
        dtype_l.append("FloatType()")

l = list(zip(name_l, dtype_l, true_l))
mySchema = eval(StructType([StructField(i) for i in l]))
mySchema
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dataType'
```

Comment: Can't you just use `spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df)`?

Comment: I believe the problem is that `StructField`'s constructor is expecting three arguments: the name of the field, its type and nullable. When passing `StructField(i)`, you are actually stating `StructField(name=(name, dtype, nullable), dtype=?, nullable=?)`. You need to unpack the tuple `i` into arguments: `StructField(*i)`.

Comment: @Idavid I had memory issue that solution.